# Obtain 'default' or 'predefined' SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR (s)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++17

Is anyone aware of an easy (easier) way to obtain or create some 'mainstream' `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` ?

In my case i just need something like an "Everyone can do anything to this" for a CreateMutex call (if I pass `NULL`(meaning default) a non-elevated user cannot obtain the mutex created by an elevated one). This is sort of the same thing you see when you look at the security tab of a file - and it can be quite verbose.

**MSDN has an example of how to create one from scratch:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/creating-a-security-descriptor-for-a-new-object-in-c--

As you can see, it is very verbose (4-5 steps needed). I guess Im hoping for a higher level function that makes this trivial or something like query the system for the "Everyone" group and copy from that, etc.

Comment: pass 0 dacl in security descriptor, this allow open for all, except appcontainer apps. also can use string form of SD and then convert it by `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW`

Comment: Check out *SID* strings: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems.

Comment: a simpel code sample to demonstrate would be great !

Comment: @darune: that would be your task :)

Comment: @ChristiFati that link is about SIDs - that is only covering one of the steps !

Comment: @RbMm 0 dacl in security descriptor - I guess that could work

Comment: As RbMm suggested, [SDDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/security-descriptor-definition-language) is the most convenient way to create a security descriptor for a new object. Knowing it is useful in general since various APIs and command-line interfaces use it. SDDL aliases also work with `ConvertStringSidToSidW` and even with icacls.exe on the command line if prefixed with an asterisk (e.g. "*BU" for "BUILTIN\Users").

Comment: for 0 dacl you can use say `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
 InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
 SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, 0, FALSE);
 SetSecurityDescriptorControl( &sd, SE_DACL_PROTECTED, SE_DACL_PROTECTED );`

Comment: or can use say next string `"D:P(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AC)"`

Comment: can even add `S:(ML;;NW;;;LW)` - access from Low Integrity. depend from what you need

Comment: "AC" is a relatively new alias for the app package context (S-1-15-2-1), defined as  `SDDL_ALL_APP_PACKAGES` in "shared/sddl.h".

Comment: @RbMm post the 0 dacl as an answer and we can close this one.